# What the error EditionsMustHaveExactlyOneToken really mean?

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, metaplex

I am using web3 to mint NFT on Solana's candy machine v2, followings all the instructions I can find.

using libraries:

```
    @project-serum/anchor": "^0.24.2",
    @solana/spl-token": "^0.2.0",
    @solana/web3.js": "^1.41.6",
```

when calling anchor.program.rpc.mintNft(xxxx); got the error

Editions must have exactly one token" string,

which is EditionsMustHaveExactlyOneToken, code is 0X10 from metaplex offical website.

I have spent days, couldn't fiugure out what is wrong. nothing you can find if you google it.

```
    0   "Program cndy3Z4yapfJBmL3ShUp5exZKqR3z33thTzeNMm2gRZ invoke [1]"    string
    1   "Program log: Instruction: MintNft" string
    2   "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]"   string
    3   "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success"  string
    4   "Program log: Index is set to 8"    string
    5   "Program log: Index actually ends up due to used bools 9"   string
    6   "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [2]"    string
    7   "Program log: Instruction: Create Metadata Accounts v2" string
    8   "Program log: Transfer 5616720 lamports to the new account" string
    9   "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]"   string
    10  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success"  string
    11  "Program log: Allocate space for the account"   string
    12  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]"   string
    13  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success"  string
    14  "Program log: Assign the account to the owning program" string
    15  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]"   string
    16  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success"  string
    17  "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 35246 of 1349634 compute units"   string
    18  "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s success"   string
    19  "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [2]"    string
    20  "Program log: V3 Create Master Edition" string
    21  "Program log: Editions must have exactly one token" string
    22  "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 10284 of 1308712 compute units"   string
    23  "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x10"    string
    24  "Program cndy3Z4yapfJBmL3ShUp5exZKqR3z33thTzeNMm2gRZ consumed 101572 of 1400000 compute units"  string
    25  "Program cndy3Z4yapfJBmL3ShUp5exZKqR3z33thTzeNMm2gRZ failed: custom program error: 0x10"    string
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete cache file and run this command: ts-node js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload     -e devnet     -k ~/config/solana/devnettest.json     -cp config.json     -c example     assets